# jQuery close button effect/style

Tags: jquery, css, button

I want to achieve an effect where a close button appears after some time of hovering the mouse on a div. How could I do that? by the way, I'm so new to jQuery.

Here is an example of something similar to what I want

[image]

That "x" in the corner I want to appear in one of my designs.

Thanks to everyone

What I have done so far:

jQuery:

```
$("#slider #content").on("hover", '.element', function(evt) {
    var top, left;
    top = $(this).offset().top;
    left = $(this).offset().left;
    $(".close-button").css({"top":top, "left":left});
    $(".close-button").show();
 });
```

The div and the styling of the div I guess is irrelevant if not, I would post it here.

Comment: My idea was to have a div as the button, and when the user hovers the div I need to close, move that hidden button to the corner of the div. I just dont know how to wait those 3 seconds before showing the "x" close div.

Comment: But what have you actually tried?

Comment: StackOverflow is not about providing "software on demand".  Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck and somebody should be able to help.

Comment: I have updated my question, but now I know how to do the fadeIn/out effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this, given the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="modalShow">show modal</a> <a href="#" class="modalShow">show modal</a>
<div class="modal">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <p>Some text in the first modal div</p>
</div>
<div class="modal">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <p>Some text in the second modal div</p>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    min-height: 6em;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
span.close {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5em;
    left: -2.5em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 2em;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('a.modalShow').click(
    function() {
        // finds which link was clicked, and therefore which modal to show
        var i = $(this).index('.modalShow'); 
        // fades all the modal elements out
        $('.modal').fadeOut(1000);
        // fades the relevant modal in
        $('.modal').eq(i).fadeIn(1000);
    });

$('.modal').hover(
    function() {
        // while hovering over the modal, it fades the close element in after a delay
        $(this).find('.close').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
    },
    function() {
        // after leaving/mouseout of the the modal, has a delay and then fades the close out
        $(this).find('.close').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    });

$('span.close').click(
    function(){
        // clicking the close span causes the closest ancestor modal to fadeout
        $(this).closest('.modal').fadeOut(1000);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VhgVV/2/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

A lot hinges on your HTML and CSS. For now, let's assume that the *box* is a div element, and the *close button* is a child div within the box. You might do something like this...

```
$(".boxes").hover(
    //do this on mouse over...
    function () {
        var me = $(this);
        me.find('.closeButton').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
    },
    //do this on mouse out...
    function () {
        var me.find('.closeButton').fadeOut(100);
    }
);
```

Comment: forgot var me = $(this) in mouse out.

Comment: You can give the closeButton a default CSS property of display:none and then let jQuery do all the heavy lifting. One thing to keep in mind is that the delay() method will only work when used with animations - which is why I used fadeIn() for the example ( instead of show() ). fadeOut() will give the element a display:none anyway, as soon as the animation is finished.